# R: how to split string correctly when there are multiple signs

Tags: r, strsplit

How to use R to split a string so that the following desired result can be achieved?

```
"A++" => "A" "" ""
"A+B+" => "A" "B" ""
"A+B+C" => "A" "B" "C"
"A++C" => "A" "" "C"
"++C" => "" "" "C"
```

I tried the `strsplit()`, the result of `strsplit("A++","\\+")[[1]]` is `"A" ""`, missing one `""`.

Comment: Why does "A++C" only have one blank?

Comment: I just wanted it to happen :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strsplit` function from the base library is somewhat limited. It drops trailing empty strings. Try the `stringr` or `stringi` libraries. For example:

```r
library(stringr)
str_split("A++", "\\+")
```

This has your required return:

```
[[1]]
[1] "A" ""  ""
```

`str_split` is vectorized over both the input string and the match pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to keep capital letters you could try the following.

```
x<-unlist((strsplit("A++",""[[1]])),use.names = F)

for(j in 1:length(x)){
  if(x[j] %in% LETTERS){x[j]<-x[j]}
  else{x[j]<-""}
}
```

You have to first use strsplit and convert from a list to a vector by using unlist. Then, simply keep anything that is a capital letter and replace all other characters with "" (R has a stored vector "LETTERS" or "letters" if you do need lowercase as well).